# CKEditor removes HTML/CSS when switching to plain texteditor and back

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

My CKEditor seems to remove formatting in a table when I switch from `plain text editor` back to `rich text editor` even though the additional formattibn was added in the `rich text editor` - it seems to persist whenb I switch to plain text but gets removed when I go back to `rich text` - I have tried around and Disabled the `ADVANCED CONTENT FILTER` under /admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full but that did not seem to help,. How can I get my changes to persist even past text editor style switches?

**EDIT 1**

My configuration under `/admin/config/content/formats/full_html` looks like below but it still doesn't seem to work correctly (yes, I also cleared my caches):
[image]

and I selected **Disabled** `/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full` - **ADVANCED CONTENT FILTER**

**EDIT 2**
Now after all these changes , on another page my content doesn't seem to properly display anymore: 
link http://www.lslib.ca/content/skwlax-wellness-centre
 problem:
under `<div class="field-item even">` I have a colorbox image declared:
`<p><a class="colorbox colorbox-insert-image init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" href="http://lslib.ca/sites/default/files/wellness%20centre.jpg" rel="gallery-all"></a></p>` and it wouldn't show up anymore in HTML and I have no idea why...

Comment: @NoSssweat please see **EDIT 1** above

Answer (score 2):

> My CKEditor seems to remove **formatting in a table**
>
> [image]

You need to add the HTML Table tags

```
<table><tr><td>
```

to your **Allowed HTML Tags**

Comment: Adding `<table><tr><td>` deidn't do the trick either...:(

Comment: I also added **EDIT 2** on top